# Compare two lines in Fortran

Tags: fortran, do-loops, read-data

I have a data file with 2 columns. Let's say:
column 1 `(8,8,8,6,9)`, reading it as `a`.
column 2 `(3,4,5,6,7)`, reading it as `b`.
I want to write a code checking if `a(i)=a(i+1)` then `b=0`.

So result should be column 1 as `a`: `(8,8,8,6,7)`, column 2 as `b` should be `(0,0,0,6,7)`.

I tried this but failed:

```
program read2cols
  implicit none

  integer ::ios,i,j
  real a,b
  open(file='8081.txt', unit=22, status='old', action='read')

do 
   read(22,*,iostat=ios) a(i),b(j)
   if(a(i)<a(i))b=0 

       if(ios/=0) exit 
     print*,a,b 
 enddo
  close(22)


end program read2cols
```

Comment: What failed? Does it compile? Does it run? Does it produce an error message? Does it completes with an erroneous result?

Comment: Also: is this the *actual code that you have run*? Parts of your code make little sense and could lead to out-of-memory access and a runaway loop.

Comment: The way I read your question, `b(i) = 0` if `a(i) == a(i+1)`. But in that case, the resulting `b` should be `(0, 0, 5, 6, 7)`, as the 3rd value of `a` is different from the 4th.

Comment: The more I look at the code, the more confused I get. `i` and `j` are never set, you are testing whether a value is smaller than itself, `a` and `b` are declared as variables, but most of the time they're addressed as arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Your program can be something like this:

```
program read2cols
  implicit none

  integer :: ios, i, j
  real :: a(5), b(5)
  open(file='8081.txt', unit=22, status='old', action='read')

  read(22, *, iostat = ios) a(1), b(1)
  do i = 2,5
    read(22, *, iostat = ios) a(i), b(i)
    if (ios /= 0) exit
    if (a(i-1) == a(i)) b(i-1) = 0
  end do

  print *, a, b
  close(22)

end program read2cols
```

Output:

```
   8.00000000       8.00000000       8.00000000       6.00000000       9.00000000       
   0.00000000       0.00000000       5.00000000       6.00000000       7.00000000
```

Notes:

You declare `a` and `b` as scalars, then index through them using `i`, fix this by declaring `a(5), b(5)` as arrays. The loop index is missing in `do ..`, it should read `do i = ..`. Finally, the condition should be `if (a(i-1) == a(i)) b(i-1) = 0` because you can compare a value only after it is read.

Comment: In the code of the question, `a` and `b` are (external) functions, not scalars.

Comment: The OP said: _column 1 (8,8,8,6,9), reading it as a.
column 2 (3,4,5,6,7), reading it as b._, so definitely not external functions but arrays containing columns of numbers.

Comment: The line `real a,b` declares `a` and `b` to be functions with return type real.  Of course, we know this to be a mistake.

Comment: @francescalus _A test for ios should probably be made before an attempt to reference the values a(i) and b(i)_, you're right about this.